# android: custom theme does not change text color and background image properly

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I wanted to create a custom theme for my app. Specifically I wanted to change the layout of the action bar and the tab indicators. After looking at some tutorials I got a custom theme which changes the background of my actionbar as well as the background for my tab indicators.
**BUT:** I am using a state list drawable for the tab indicator and for some reason it does not properly display the "selected" state of the tab indicator. It does only do so while I am pressing the tab indicator. Also for some reason I can't get the text color in the tab indicator to change.

The XML for the custom tab indicator looks like this

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabs"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_tab_indicator</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_tab_indicator</item>

    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>

</style>
```

the one for the custom theme looks like this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#000000</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#000000</item>


    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>


</style>
```

the style I defined for the text color of the tab indicator looks like this

```
<style name="MyTabTextStyle"
    parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">9pt</item>
</style>
```

the state list drawable looks like this

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/days_line" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/days_line" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/days_line" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/days_line" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected_day" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected_day" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected_day" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected_day" />
```

basically I just got most of the xml out of the android documentation itself and just changed the pictures etc.
Also I can't seem to find a way to fixate the tab indicators. I will always have 5 tabs "monday to friday" and they should be always displayed at the same position, but at the moment the tab indicators are side scrollable by default.

I know these are a lot of questions but they all seem related. Please let me know if I missed something important e.g. some information that will help examine my problem more thoroughly. I think maybe I am just missing a small thing but I spent over a whole day with this problem now and the documentation itself does not explain more than what I have got here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

the first thing was pretty easy to solve, I fucked up with the state list drawable (had to change the background pictures to respond to the right selected, focused and pressed states).

The other problem was that the color of the tab text didn't change. Turns out you have to definie it in the theme itself and not in the action bar tab theme like so:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    <!--for support library-->
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
```